# Baud Rate changing Break Command in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, bluetooth

I am using AirCable Serial5 Bluetooth adapter for RS232 to Bluetooth transfer. I need to change Baudrate from lower 9600 to 115200. I talked with AirCable supplier and he said that, for that I have to send Baud changing Break command(0x85) to serial COM port. I don't know how to send break command with baud changing HEX code in VB.NET

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
    Private Sp As New SerialPort
    Private comBuffer As Byte()
    Private Delegate Sub UpdateFormDelegate()    
    Private UpdateFormDelegate1 As UpdateFormDelegate    
    Dim m As Integer    

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load    
        With Sp    
            .PortName = "COM8"    
            .BaudRate = 9600    
            .DataBits = 8    
            .Parity = Parity.None    
            .StopBits = StopBits.One    
            .Handshake = Handshake.None    

        End With    
        Try    
            Sp.Open()    
        Catch ex As Exception    
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)    
        End Try    

        AddHandler Sp.DataReceived, AddressOf Sp_DataReceived    

        Sp.Write("s r0x90 115200" + vbCr)    
        Thread.Sleep(100)    

    End Sub    

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing    
        Sp.Write("s r0x90 9600" + vbCr)    
        Thread.Sleep(100)    
    End Sub    

    Private Sub getBD_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles getBD.Click    
        Sp.Write("g r0x90" + vbCr)    
        Thread.Sleep(100)    

    End Sub

    Private Sub Sp_DataReceived(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)    

        'Handles serial port data received events     
        UpdateFormDelegate1 = New UpdateFormDelegate(AddressOf UpdateDisplay)    
        Dim n As Integer = Sp.BytesToRead 'find number of bytes in buffer    
        m = n    
        comBuffer = New Byte(n - 1) {} 're dimension storage buffer     
        Sp.Read(comBuffer, 0, n) 'read data from the buffer     

        Me.Invoke(UpdateFormDelegate1) 'call the delegate     
    End Sub    

    Private Sub UpdateDisplay()     
        ' updates label text    

        'Label1.Text = ""    
        Dim b As Integer = 0    

        Do Until b = m    

            Dim array() As Byte = {CStr(comBuffer(b))}    
            Dim value As String = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(array)    
            Label1.Text += value    
            b += 1    
        Loop    
    End Sub     

    Private Sub snd_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles snd.Click    
        Dim x As String    
        x = cmdBox.Text    
        Sp.Write(x + vbCr)    
        Thread.Sleep(100)    
    End Sub    

End Class
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I have a question.  What is your question?
Are you asking us to translate `s r0x90 11500` into hex???

Comment: The obvious.  Have you tried just setting the port speed to 115200?  Another thing, some of the bluetooth serial adapters will run as fast as you can send bytes.  I have had them run as fast as 2Mbps.

Comment: @dbasnett - This program is actually controlling Stepper motor controller and it maximum port speed is just 115200.

Comment: @Grim - Sorry for late reply. I am not asking to translate to hex. Actually "s r0x90 115200" is just a command for Stepper motor controller to change its Baud Rate. Actually my question is about Bluetooth adapter. After changing a Baud rate of Stepper motor controller to 115200. I have to change Bluetooth adapter Baud rate, so i can send and receive data back again. Now, to change baudrate on Bluetooth is little tricky. I have to write Hex code "0x85" to Serial port break command to change Baud Rate on Bluetooth. I don't know how to send/write "0x85" on serial port break code.